# Anyone managed to have a dynamic default store view?

Tags: store-view

Due to different locales having more natural default values than others, the wish is to be able to have store views inherit values of a different store view rather than the common default store view (Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) where default values are fetched from.

There is one constant indicating the default store view but a variety of classes write their own wrapper to that constant.

Has anyone ever implemented this behavior and how did you approach it? Does anyone have pointers on how to most elegantly solve this?

Comment: Do you mean for config-related values or for catalog-related values?

Comment: @benmarks Catalog. But a solution has already been found. Should find some time to answer the question/detail a possible solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you had in mind but there is a free open source module to copy values from one store view to another, using a mass action in the product grid:

**AvS_StoreViewCopy**: https://github.com/avstudnitz/StoreViewCopy

It was developed for the use case of different websites that have store views with the same language, so it might work for you too.